# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS does not recognise wireless ethernet card

Tags: 12.04, wireless, virtualization

Setup Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS as a VM on windows 8 host PC. But the wireless card is not recognised though the virtual switch comprising of the wireless card (intel centrino) has been added as network adapter

Comment: Please consider adding more information. Please add your system specifications and your wireless Ethernet card specs also.

Comment: Try to change the network settings on your virtual machine. E.g. I had more luck with a »bridged adapter« with Linux VM's

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

Your PCI(e) wireless device will not be recognized and used in a virtual machine. Networking is by a bridged virtual interface to the hosts system networking device; wired or wireless. For an example, please see here: http://pubs.vmware.com/ws8/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=using_ws/GUID-BAFA66C3-81F0-4FCA-84C4-D9F7D258A60A.html#1_14_9_1

```
With bridged networking, the virtual network adapter in the virtual machine
connects to a physical network adapter in the host system. The host network
adapter enables the virtual machine to connect to the LAN that the host system 
uses. Bridged networking works with both wired and wireless host network adapters.
```